# open new item form through custom action

Tags: 2010, custom-actions

I have created a custom action which visible to user on "Issue" Display Form.

I have another list called "Note" which has a look field (Type of Issue) called Issue. Basically there is one to many relation between Issue and Note.

So, when user views an issue and click on Add Note custom action, I would like to open a new Note item form and set the Issue to the issue action was fired of.

Do I need to use Visual Studio for this or is it something doable via sharepoint designer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SharePoint and SharePoint designer 2010.

Without being able to post pictures all I can really do is refer you to a great tutorial I just went through myself.

Pay attention to the use of custom new item form web part, web part parameters, and then using Javascript to call the NewItem2 method to pass a parameter to the NewItems.aspx form.

I hope this will help.  I found the tutorial covers a lot of ground.

[SharePoint Hillbilly](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx)